# How to show in general a certain type of metric generates a certain type of topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

If we're given a set $X$ together with a metric $d: X \times X \to \mathbb R^+$, and a topology $ \mathcal F \subset 2^X$. What do we need to do in order to show this metric generates this topology?

Comment: You need to show that the $\varepsilon$ balls in $X$ are a basis for $\mathcal F$.

Comment: So can I do by first showing that each $\epsilon$ ball is in $\mathcal F$, and then show that every $ E \in \mathcal F$ is a union of countable intersections balls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your $X=\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology say $\tau$ and $d$ is the usual absolute value metric on $\mathbb{R}$. What do you do to show that the topology generated by $d$ is same as the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ ? You start with a basic open set $U$ in $\tau$ and given any $x\in \tau$ you show that we can find an $\epsilon >0$ such that the $\epsilon$-ball centred at $x$ is contained in $U$. Conversely, you take $B(x,\epsilon)$, the $\epsilon$-ball centred at any point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and for any $y\in B(x,\epsilon)$ you show that $\exists$ an open set $U\in \tau$ such that $y\in U$ and $U\subset B(x,\epsilon)$.

The same argument works for any set $X$ with a metric $d$.

Comment: i'm gald that it helped :)